# Scroll to repeated element

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollto

I have been using the `ScrollTo` script (`jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js`) to smoothly scroll to each post on a wordpress blog. Since newer versions of jQuery, this code has stopped working. Here is where I originally found the code:http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/scrollto-posts-with-jquery

Does anyone have a suggestion or better method for getting this functionality?

Here is a fiddle, the `prev`, `next` links should elicit scroll to the neighboring `.post` divs

http://jsfiddle.net/bTfKk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's missing the easings, so when you remove those it works. From:

```
$.scrollTo(scroll, {
     duration: 300, easing:'easeOutExpo'      
});
```

to:

```
$.scrollTo(scroll, {
     duration: 300
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bTfKk/1/)

Or you can add jQuery UI or just the [easings library](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) : http://jsfiddle.net/bTfKk/2/